# Kotlin: How to bypass CancellationException

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

I'm porting some old RxJava code to Coroutines. With RxJava I could do this in my activity:

```
someBgOperation()
.as(AutoDispose.autoDisposable(AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(MyActivity.this)))
.subscribe(
    MyActivity.this::onSuccess,
    MyActivity.this::onError
);
```

The autodispose library would cancel the Observable if the activity was being closed. In this case RxJava would not call the error handler, so it was possible to do UI-related operations in the error handler safely, such as showing a dialog.

Now in Kotlin we could have this equivalent code launched from `lifecycleScope` in the Activity, or in a `viewModelScope` if using ViewModel:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        someBgOperation()
    } catch (e: Exception){
        //show dialog
    }
}
```

Both scopes are automatically cancelled when the activity closes, just what Autodispose does. But the catch block will execute not only with normal errors thrown by `someBgOperation` itself, but also with `CancellationException`s that are used by the coroutines library under the hood to handle cancellation. If I try to show a dialog there while the activity is being closed, I might get new exceptions. So I'm forced to do something like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        someBgOperation()
    } catch (ce: CancellationException){
        //do nothing, activity is closing
    } catch (e: Exception){
        //show dialog
    }
}
```

This feels more verbose than the Rx version and it has an empty catch clause, which would show a warning in the lint output. In other cases where I do more things after the try-catch, I'm forced to return from the `CancellationException` catch to stay UI-safe (and those returns are tagged returns). I'm finding myself repeating this ugly template again and again.

Is there a better way of ignoring the CancellationException?

Answer (score 7):

I can propose two solutions. First of all, the additional `catch(e: CancellationException)` clause looks a bit verbose. You can simplify the code to:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        someBgOperation()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (e !is CancellationException) // show dialog
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you can use Kotlin Flow whose `catch` operator is designed to ignore cancellations exactly for this purpose. Since you are not actually will be sending any values over the flow, your should use `Flow<Nothing>`:

```
flow<Nothing> {
    someBgOperation()
}.catch { e ->
    // show dialog
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree, your try-catch is less verbose, but I'm not a fan of single line `if`'s. If only a negative catch existed, like `} catch (e: !CancellationException){`.

Comment: The flow solution is beautiful. I personally prefer chaining over try-catch for error handling. I presume the porting from Rx would be easier as well.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: revised, since CancellationExceptions should not be swallowed.

You could create a helper function that converts to a `Result` so you can handle only non-cancellation Exceptions:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.runCatchingCancellable(block: T.() -> R): Result<R> {
    return try {
        Result.success(block())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e is CancellationException) {
            throw e
        }
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    runCatchingCancellable {
        someBgOperation()
    }.onFailure { e ->
        //show dialog
    }
}
```

And this function can serve as a safe alternative to `runCatching` to use in cancellable coroutines.

Comment: You might consider building this out of [`runCatching`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html) instead of inventing your own wrappers.

Comment: I was already thinking on how this need could be solved with a little library or extension function. I wonder why Kotlin devs didn't though of it (maybe they don't catch exceptions at all!)

Comment: shouldn't you rethrow the `CancellationException` here?

Comment: @Bhargav Yes, I revised it.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this slightly cleaner syntax:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        someBgOperation()
    } catch (e: Exception){
        if (isActive) {
            //show dialog
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't, it will still swallow the CancellationException